# Permission denied for module.h

Tags: module, kernel

/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h

when i am trying to run this command as a root user its showing following error

bash: /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h: Permission denied

plzz help!
Thanx

Comment: That command would try to run module.h but module.h is not an executable so it is not allowed resulting in a permission denied error. I suspect that running the file is not what you want to do, if you want to see the contents of module.h use `less /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run "/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h"? It's not one executable command at all. It's a header file in the Linux Kernel source tree.

Comment: yes i did that but how can i compile a device driver including this as a header file??

Comment: There is a file in the kernel source tree: ./Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt, in this document, you can learn how to compile a device driver.